# Include_Path Zend_Framework

Tags: php, include-path

```
    Error: [2] require_once(Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

/var/www/vhosts/localhost/httpdocs/public.:./var/www/vhosts/localhost/httpdocs/public/../library:./var/www/vhosts/localhost/httpdocs/public/../model:.


defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : define('SITE_ROOT',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);

$includePath[] = '.';
$includePath[] = '.' . SITE_ROOT . '/../library';
$includePath[] = '.' . SITE_ROOT . '/../model';
$includePath[] = get_include_path();
$includePath = implode(PATH_SEPARATOR,$includePath);
set_include_path($includePath);




require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
```

Please help me setting properly set_include_path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using lines such as this :

```
$includePath[] = '.' . SITE_ROOT . '/../library';
```

Which get you an include_path such as this :

```
./var/www/vhosts/localhost/httpdocs/public/../library
```

Note the `.` at the beginning of that path -- I'm guessing it shouldn't be there.

Try removing thoses `.` at the beginning of each path :

```
$includePath[] = '.';
$includePath[] = SITE_ROOT . '/../library';
$includePath[] = SITE_ROOT . '/../model';
$includePath[] = get_include_path();
$includePath = implode(PATH_SEPARATOR,$includePath);
set_include_path($includePath);
```

For information : A `.` in a UNIX path means "*current directory*" ; and a `/` at the beginning of a path means "*the root of the server*".

So, a path such as `./var/www` actually means *"the `www` directory that is inside the `var` directory that is inside the current directory"*.

And you probably need something like *"the `www` directory that's inside the `var` directory that's at the root of the server."*

Comment: Ok it went fine now. Again the main problem was in lowercase&Uppercase difference in filenames and names inside php include functions.